# Android Admob banner display always front the page

Tags: android, xml, admob

My banner adview only display front like screenshot.

My xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentReplace"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

how can i fix it?

Thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgDIq.png)

Comment: like screenshote means??

Comment: display perfectly smart banner

Answer (score 0):

add below code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

What you want to fix.